# How could a mind storing device exist where the creators can implant their minds into mindless beings when the nuclear war happening is over?

Tags: technology, warfare, sim-humans

Could this be possible in some ways:

1. A mind device or Black Box that holds the minds of a few humans without needing a body.
2. The brains can exist in the Black Box freely, a place alike the holodeck in Star Trek where the leaders or creators of the box control the settings.
3. This Black Box can survive a world wide nuclear attack and the minds in the Black Box never die but also don't have bodies in the reality on Earth.
4. The humans want to go back to Earth once Earth has recovered, but how would they find other living beings to implant their minds into if everyone died in the nuclear war?
5. Could the people make mindless bodies waiting for them once the nuclear war is over and implant their minds into their bodies?
6. What would the effects be on a child if they were to live in a place like the Black Box for 5 to 10 years?

Comment: Since this "Black Box" is invented for your setting and there's no real-world equivalent, the answers would be: Whatever you want it to be.

Comment: Didn't we have a question a lot like this a month or two ago?  Something about mages controlling the minds of the recently deceased?  I haven't had a chance to search for the duplicate, but this might be a duplicate.

Comment: @AnnaBanana Hi, and welcome to Worldbuilding SE! Generally, you will want to avoid accepting an answer for at least 24 hours, as there are people all over the world who would like to answer these kinds of question, but are discouraged if question already has an answer. So give the question some time to collect some answers, and I am sure you will find a few interesting ones!

Answer (score 0):

3D printed bodies. We can currently take some stemcells off of someone, force it into a specific celltype you want, grow those celltypes in the lab and then "print" it into the shape you want. This technology is limited right now, but assuming it gets advanced while the Black Box tech is advanced, they would simply have biological paste waiting, a databank of DNA and from there they would first create the cells and then build the entire body to whatever specifications they want. You want to be as smart as John Neumann and Albert Einstein? Get the brain's pathway printed similar to theirs (I assume that if you can path someone's brain and copy it you can build it to specifications as well).

And there you have a way to create bodies. Alternatively, they just have robots available to them and a manufactory to build more. This way they can venture out through remote control, check if it's safe and only enter fullscale robotic/cybernetic bodies once they think it's safe enough and they can find enough powersources to keep going outside.

Answer (score 0):

As for the child being in the black box question, there are two options.

1: The mind is asleep and the mind awakes in a new body

2: The black box is actually a VR world where the mind can grow, learn and mature virtually. It would be no different to real life and would be modeled as such.